# Dojo's dijit.calendar and isDisabledDate

Tags: dojo

I'd like to use the dijit.calendar widget, but be able to set disabled dates from an array of dates. All the examples point out how to disable weekends, but I need to disable special dates too.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to utilize a custom function in the isDisabledDate, rather than just whats in dojo.date.locale?

I've tried writing a function, and putting it inside the isDisabledDate attribute, but all I get is errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a huge assumption here, that you're populating your array for each month displayed via an XHR request. This XHR request returns an array of strings in Y-m-d format (i.e. ['2011-11-29','2011-11-30']). Another slight assumption is that the XHR request returns an array of dates that should be enabled, but this can be reversed by swapping the `disable = true;` and `disable = false;` lines

I don't know how much detail to go into without being patronizing, so if anything is unclear I'll try to clarify afterwards.

```
dojo.provide("custom.Calendar");
dojo.declare("custom.Calendar", dijit.Calendar, {
    _xhr: null,
    // Month/Year navigation buttons clicked
    _adjustDisplay: function(){
        // Ensure all dates are initially enabled (prevents seepage)
        this.isDisabledDate = function(date) {
            return false;
        };
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._disableAndPopulate();
    },
    constructor: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._disableAndPopulate();
    },
    // Month drop down box
    _onMonthSelect: function(){
        // Ensure all dates are initially enabled (prevents seepage)
        this.isDisabledDate = function(date) {
            return false;
        };
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._disableAndPopulate();
    },
    // Set disabled dates and re-render calendar
    _disableAndPopulate: function(){
        var currDate = this.currentFocus;

        // Get Lower bound date
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setFullYear(currDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getMonth(), -5);
        // Create ymd dates manually (10x faster than dojo.date.locale.format)
        var startMonth = (startDate.getMonth()<9 ? '0' + (startDate.getMonth()+1) : startDate.getMonth()+1);
        var startDay = (startDate.getDate()<10 ? '0' + startDate.getDate() : startDate.getDate());
        var ymdStartDate = startDate.getFullYear() + '-' + startMonth + '-' + startDay;

        // Get Upper bound date
        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setFullYear(currDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getMonth() + 1, 14);
        // Create ymd dates manually (10x faster than dojo.date.locale.format)
        var endMonth = (endDate.getMonth()<9 ? '0' + (endDate.getMonth()+1) : endDate.getMonth()+1);
        var endDay = (endDate.getDate()<10 ? '0' + endDate.getDate() : endDate.getDate());
        var ymdEndDate = endDate.getFullYear() + '-' + endMonth + '-' + endDay;

        var calendar = this;
        // Get IssueDates
        var issueDates;
        // If an existing xhr request is still running, cancel it before starting a new one
        if (this._xhr) {
            this._xhr.cancel();
        }
        this._xhr = dojo.xhrGet({
            url: "http://.....", // url of server-side script
            content: {
                startDate: ymdStartDate, // Earliest possible date displayed on current month
                endDate: ymdEndDate, // Last possible date displayed on current month
                filters: {} // Any additional criteria which your server-side script uses to determine which dates to return
            },
            failOk: true, // Prevent error being logged to console when previous XHR calls are cancelled
            load: function(data){
                issueDates = dojo.fromJson(data);
                if (issueDates === undefined) {
                    // Error with xhr
                } else {
                    calendar.isDisabledDate = function(date) {
                        var disable = true;
                        // Create ymdDate manually (10x faster than dojo.date.locale.format)
                        var month = (date.getMonth()<9 ? '0' + (date.getMonth()+1) : date.getMonth()+1);
                        var day = (date.getDate()<10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate());
                        var ymdDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                        // Loop through array returned from XHR request, if it contains current date then
                        // current date should not be disabled
                        for (key in issueDates) {
                            if (issueDates[key] == ymdDate) {
                                disable = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return disable;
                    };
                    calendar._populateGrid(); // Refresh calendar display
                }
            },
            // Log any errors to console (except when XHR request is cancelled)
            error: function(args) {
                if (args.dojoType == 'cancel') {
                    // Request cancelled
                } else {
                    console.error(args);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    onClose: function() {
        // If an existing xhr request is still running, cancel it before starting a new one
        if (this._xhr) {
            this._xhr.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

AMD style:
**CalendarLite.js.uncompressed.js** in **dojo 1.7.1** contains the **isDisabledDate** function:

```
isDisabledDate: function(/*===== dateObject, locale =====*/){
    // summary:
    //      May be overridden to disable certain dates in the calendar e.g. `isDisabledDate=dojo.date.locale.isWeekend`
    // dateObject: Date
    // locale: String?
    // tags:
    //      extension
/*=====
    return false; // Boolean
=====*/
},
...
```

You could re-implement the function using this example:

```
var myCalendar = declare(Calendar, {
    datesToDisable : [],

    constructor: function(args) {
        this.inherited("constructor", arguments);
        this.datesToDisable = args.datesToDisable;
    },

    isDisabledDate: function(/*Date*/date, /*String?*/locale){
        return array.some(this.datesToDisable, function(item) {
            return dojo.compare(item, date, "date") === 0;
        });
    }
});
```

Then you can use the following constructor and datesToDisable parameter to specify your array.

```
var someCalendar = new myCalendar({datesToDisable: [new Date(...),....,new Date(....)]},...);
```

or try this for a fast and dirty solution:

```
var someCalendar = new Calendar(...);
someCalendar.datesToDisable = [new Date(...),....,new Date(....)];
someCalendar.isDisabledDate = function(/*Date*/date, /*String?*/locale){
        return array.some(this.datesToDisable, function(item) {
            return date.compare(item, date, "date") === 0;
        });
}
```

But I would recommend the **first** approach. The assumption is that you know AMD style in order to "import" **dijit/Calendar**, **dojo/_base/array** and **dojo/date** (for "date.compare()" to work).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can add list of holidays in an array with its timestamp and use indexOf method to find matching dates while populating the calendar in the overriding function of isDisabledDate

```
var holidays = new Array();
var holidDt = new Date("October 2, 2012");
holidays.push(holidDt.getTime());
```

Now access the holiday array and check its presence. If present disable, else enable by overriding the `isDisabledDate` function

```
isDisabledDate: function(d) {
    var dt = new Date(d);
    var dayN = dt.getDay();
    dt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /**
     * Condition for 
     * 1. Weekends
     * 2. Holidays (holiday array needs to be updated with holiday times)
     */
    return ((!((dayN > 0) && (dayN < 6))) || (arrayUtil.indexOf(holidays, dt.getTime()) >= 0));
}
```